# Is it possible using Detox inside native project?

Tags: react-native, testing, automation, detox

Is it possible to use Detox Tool to test my React Native app, which is inside on native project?

I have a React Native project but the .apk file belong to Android native project, and when I open an specific module, the React Native app is going to open, and then I would want to test my app.

I'm trying test this by starting Mocha with `yarn start`, and then open the module on native app to load my react native modulo. And when start Detox with `detox test --configuration android.emu.debug` it give me this answer:

```
12:21:58.172 detox[51738] B jest --config e2e/jest.config.js
 FAIL  e2e/starter.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Failed to find the app binary at:
    /Users/dieh1984/Documents/Projects/mobile-projects/loans-app/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

    HINT: Make sure that:
    1. You built the app before running tests:
      detox build -c <your-configuration-name>
    2. The app binary can be found at the given path.
        at _reinstallAppsOnDevice.next (<anonymous>)

      at getNextResult (node_modules/caf/src/caf.js:253:25)
      at DetoxWorker.runner (node_modules/caf/src/caf.js:293:5)
      at DetoxWorker.instance [as _reinstallAppsOnDevice] (node_modules/caf/src/caf.js:63:32)
          at init.next (<anonymous>)
      at getNextResult (node_modules/caf/src/caf.js:253:25)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.713 s
Ran all test suites.
12:21:59.301 detox[51738] E Command failed with exit code = 1:
jest --config e2e/jest.config.js
```

Of course, that error is because the url `/Users/dieh1984/Documents/Projects/mobile-projects/loans-app/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk` doesn't exist in my react native project.

I hope someone can help me!